# App.css in laravel moves to previous state

Tags: laravel-5.1

Whenever I change something in app.css and then in app.scss and run npm run development, all my changes in app.css file vanished and previous state of the file appeared. How to save the changes in app.css in laravel

Comment: You shouldn't edit the generated code. Make all your changes in scss. Why is that a problem?

Comment: Ya I can do that but tell me how to override the css codes of that file